# How to set the win8 toast icon through desktop program

Tags: wpf, windows, toast

I want to notify custom through Toast, and my program is desktop program(WPF).
When I finish it ,I found the icon of toast is default windows soft icon, not my program's.
So I want to konw how to set it?